# macOS, delete profiles that need password

Tags: macos, configuration-profiles

There is a profile I installed many days ago and I forget the password, how can I delete it?

[image]

Comment: I’ll leave the cracking to others, but I’m sure someone has tried the non brute force method I’ll propose as a fall back to surgically removing these profiles that are locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to delete the profile by using this command

```
sudo profiles remove -forced -identifier=com.apple.mdm.macdm.22fba6f0-ff19-0138-d02e-003ee1c5a824.alacarte
```

Use this command to find the profile name

```
sudo profiles -Lv | grep "name: $4" -4 | grep -E 'name|profileIdentifier' | awk -F ': ' 'BEGIN {key = ""} { if (NR%2==1){key=$3}else{print key"==="$3}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can back up the Mac and then boot to recovery and erase it. The MDM profiles are designed to resist cracking so erase and restore is often the fastest method.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904